# check array elements in json object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array:

```
var arr = [20122, 20133, 20144, 20155, 20177];
```

And I have a JSON object:

```
[{
    "ext": "20177",
    "name": "SIP\/20177-000001e8",
    "state": "Ringing"
}, {
    "ext": "20122",
    "name": "SIP\/20122-000001e7",
    "state": "Ringing"
}]
```

I need to check the array as an input and check if the array values exist or not in the `JSON` object.

I tried like below:

```
var arr = [20122, 20133, 20144, 20155, 20177];
jQuery.map(resp, function(obj) {
  if(jQuery.inArray(obj.ext,arr) == -1){
    //not exist
  }                     
})
```

But here JSON is the input. But I need the array as input.

Comment: what do you want to do after the check?

Comment: It's being much clear. Thanks, @nnnnnn.

Comment: you need to convert the json `ext` properies into an array usinh `map`, then you can check if any of this array exist in the `arr` array.

Comment: You don't have "a json object", because [there's no such thing as a json object.](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). Either you have JSON, which is a string that you need to parse, or you already have an array of objects. From the code shown we can't tell which because you don't show how `resp` is set.

Comment: Try underscore http://underscorejs.org/#map

Comment: @nnnnnn: Indeed. raavi, here's [another handy link on that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247). Given the name `resp`, though, we can suspect it's probably an ajax response jQuery parsed automatically. :-)

Comment: @Venkatraman: There's no need to add another library in the above. JavaScript's own `Array#map`, `Array#indexOf`, `Array#find` and such are entirely up to the task.

Comment: totaly agreed @T.J.Crowder. then why we need to use jQuery array functions ?

Comment: @Venkatraman: In 2016? We don't. :-) They were handy in 2008, though, before there were standard semantics for these things (inspired in part by jQuery, Underscore, and PrototypeJS).

Comment: Fine. @raavi, add your expected output in the Question

Comment: @Venkatraman - Even if supporting old browsers that don't implement array `.map()` natively, there's no need to include Underscore *as well* when OP is already using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you don't really have JSON (a string) in `resp` (remember, JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange; if you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON), but that it's already been parsed into an array of objects (perhaps jQuery did it for you, if `resp` is the response of an ajax call). (If `resp` is a string containing `JSON`, parse it with `JSON.parse` and then continue with the rest of the answer.)

`inArray` does an `===` (type and value) check. Your array contains *numbers*. Your object's `ext` property values are *strings*.

Either change your array to contain strings, or perhaps convert the `ext` property values to numbers as you compare:

```
if(jQuery.inArray(+obj.ext,arr) == -1){
// ---------------^
```

Also note that you'd normally use the return value of `jQuery.map` for something; otherwise, you'd use `jQuery.each`.

Example (keeping `jQuery.map` in case you are using the result):

```js
var resp = [{"ext":"20177","name":"SIP\/20177-000001e8","state":"Ringing"},{"ext":"20122","name":"SIP\/20122-000001e7","state":"Ringing"}];

var arr = [20122, 20133, 20144, 20155, 20177];
jQuery.map(resp, function(obj) {
  if(jQuery.inArray(+obj.ext,arr) == -1){
    // -------------^
    console.log("Not found: " + obj.ext);
  } else {
    console.log("Found: " + obj.ext);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Side note: If you're using an even vaguely modern browser, you can use built-in array features rather than `jQuery.map`, `jQuery.each`, and `jQuery.inArray`: They're the `map`, `forEach`, and `indexOf` methods on arrays themselves. They're all polyfillable/shimmable on older browsers as well.

For example:

```js
var resp = [{"ext":"20177","name":"SIP\/20177-000001e8","state":"Ringing"},{"ext":"20122","name":"SIP\/20122-000001e7","state":"Ringing"}];

var arr = [20122, 20133, 20144, 20155, 20177];
resp.forEach(function(obj) {
  if(arr.indexOf(+obj.ext) == -1){
    console.log("Not found: " + obj.ext);
  } else {
    console.log("Found: " + obj.ext);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the input is JSON then you need to parse it first: `var data = JSON.parse(resp);`. Example bellow:

```js
var arr = [20122, 20133, 20144, 20155, 20177];
var resp = '[{"ext":"20177","name":"SIP\/20177-000001e8","state":"Ringing"},{"ext":"20122","name":"SIP\/20122-000001e7","state":"Ringing"}]';

var data = JSON.parse(resp); //<-- You need this to convert json to array

jQuery.each(data, function(i, obj) {
  if(jQuery.inArray(obj.ext, arr) == -1){
    console.log(obj.name+' Exists');
  }                     
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var arr = [20122, 20133, 20144, 20155, 20177],
resp = [{"ext":"20177","name":"SIP\/20177-000001e8","state":"Ringing"},{"ext":"20122","name":"SIP\/20122-000001e7","state":"Ringing"}],

 $.each(arr, function (i, arritem) {
            $.each(resp , function (i, jsonitem) {
               if(obj.ext==arritem)
               {
               //match
               }
               else
               {
                //not match
               }
            }
 }
```

Comment: Please add more  details to the solution you provide

Answer (score 1):

According to your requirement *"But I need the array as input"* - consider  the following solution using `Array.forEach` and `Array.map` functions in ES6 "manner":

```
var arr = [20122, 20133, 20144, 20155, 20177],
    resp = [{"ext":"20177","name":"SIP\/20177-000001e8","state":"Ringing"},{"ext":"20122","name":"SIP\/20122-000001e7","state":"Ringing"}],
    exts = resp.map((o) => +o.ext),
    result = {};

arr.forEach((v) => result[v] = (exts.indexOf(v) !== -1)? 1 : 0 );

console.log(result);
// value 1 means that arr value exists within json objects, 0 - not exists
// Object {20122: 1, 20133: 0, 20144: 0, 20155: 0, 20177: 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  var arr = [20122, 20133, 20144, 20155, 20177];
  var oJson = [{"ext":"20177","name":"SIP/20177-000001e8","state":"Ringing"},{"ext":"20122","name":"SIP/20122-000001e7","state":"Ringing"}]

  $('button').on('click', function(e) {
    var newArr = [];
    
    $.each(oJson, function(key, value) {
      if ($.inArray(value.ext, arr))
        newArr.push(value.ext);
    });
    
    console.log(newArr);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Check</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [**find**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) array method & [**forEach**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to check if element exist in json

If such a json object exist , `find` will return the object else it will return undefined.
+ is used for string to number conversion , since in `arr` the elements are number while in `jsonObj` they are string

```
var arr = [20122, 20133, 20144, 20155, 20177];
var jsonObj=[{"ext":"20177","name":"SIP\/20177-000001e8","state":"Ringing"},{"ext":"20122","name":"SIP\/20122-000001e7","state":"Ringing"}]

arr.forEach(function(item){
 var _getValue ="";  
     var _isPresent=jsonObj.find(function(item2){
      if(item == +item2.ext){
        return item2;
       }
        else{
         return false;
        }
})
if(_isPresent !== undefined){
   _getValue =_isPresent.ext;
}
else{
  _getValue="Not matched";
}
document.write('<pre>'+_getValue+'</pre>')
})
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/qo87rahp/)